# javascript find element with string as id

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function to with the element in my page with id equal to a string, and append children to that element. However I'm not so familiar with JS and don't know what's wrong with my function. Here is the function. The "set" is just an array as string set(It contains multiple names).

```
    function printNetwork(set,id){
        console.log("id is "+id);
        var node=document.getElementById(id);
        console.log("found"+node);
        for(var s in set){
            var className="leaf";
            var content = document.createTextNode("<p class="+className+">"+s+"</p>");
            console.log(content);
            node.appendChild(content);
        }
    }
```

And then I called the function:

```
    var ced ="${commented}";
    console.log(ced);//ced is like "[&quot;Mike&quot;]"
    var cedArr = JSON.parse(ced.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'));//parse it back to set
    console.log(cedArr);
    printNetwork(cedArr,"ced");
```

Reading the log from console it says "node" is foundnull, and "content" is "`<p class=leaf>0</p>`" and appendChild failed.
My question is, how can I pass the id into the function where it searches element by the argument? I'm used to the way Java works and now I'm a little confused with how JS works...

Suggestions are appreciated!!

Comment: do you have an element with id `ced` in your DOM?

Comment: Is `set` an `Array`, or an `Object`? There is a VERY important difference there, and if it is in fact an `Array`, you cannot use the `for` syntax employed here. (`myArray.forEach(function(s) { ...` is a good alternative)

Comment: @Katana314 Thanks for reminding me! Yes the for syntax doesn't work and I'm trying out foreach.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work, i've used a different array than yours to make the example simple, but my guess is that you don't have any element with id `ced` in your DOM:

```
function printNetwork(set,id){
    console.log("id is "+id);
    var node=document.getElementById(id);
    console.log("found"+node);
    for(var s in set){
        var className="leaf";
        var content = document.createTextNode("<p class="+className+">"+s+"</p>");
        console.log(content);
        node.appendChild(content);
    }
}

var ced = {"a": "a", "b": "b"};
printNetwork(ced,"ced");
```

And html:

```
<div id="ced"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eakvdr7L/

Comment: Today I had a few tests and found that the element was not found because I put the JS before that div with id="ced". Also the "set" is an array in form ["a","b"] so I'd better change the format of my function. Thanks for reply!